# How to improve prediction of deep learning regression model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, regression

I have dataset of 50 000 rows ranging from 35-50 columns, and based on it i need to predict 3 values for each row.

> e.g. 43208.7032; (37 increasing values); 48743.4976 -> 3.7707; 372.9719; 1.158718

By far the best results i've got are mean absolute error nearing 0.05, while i need it to be near 0.001-0.0005.

I have filled the missing data with zeros, and normalized the X with keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization, created callback:

```
callbackPlateau = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss',
    factor=0.8,
    patience=5,
    verbose=1,
    mode='min',
    min_lr=0.0000001
)
```

and created the model which gives results nearing 0.05 mean_absolute_error:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=amount_of_columns, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.6)))
model.add(Dense(90, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
model.add(Dense(270, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
model.add(Dense(90, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
model.add(Dense(45, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
model.add(Dense(15, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
model.add(Dense(45, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
model.add(Dense(3, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.4)))
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=opt)
```

And i train it:

```
history = model.fit(
    training_x, 
    training_y, 
    epochs=550, 
    batch_size=128, 
    callbacks=[callbackPlateau, callbackEarly], 
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y))
```

which on the last epoch gives:

```
Epoch 343/550
274/274 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0409 - val_loss: 0.0507

Epoch 00343: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 6.805647899454925e-07.
Epoch 00343: early stopping
```

and evaluates into:

```
79/79 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0476
```

Here is my loss plot:
[Image of plot loss+val_loss/epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfU8v.png)

And here example results:

```
 Example predictions:
3.6658335; 374.98608; 1.2702768 (expected 3.6646; 374.9678; 1.271311), abs_err: 0.0025;
3.742614; 373.0805; 1.1156969 (expected 3.7444; 373.0549; 1.116855), abs_err: 0.0032;
3.6771998; 369.40353; 1.2375629 (expected 3.6812; 369.4603; 1.231281), abs_err: 0.0108;


 Worst:
3.5641375; 362.88254; 1.1704892 (expected 3.6136; 376.969; 1.137181), abs_err: 0.2236;
```

I have tried various amounts of nodes and layers, and i tried using linear and relu activation.

Is there anything i can do better or additionally to make the model give better final results?
It's my first deep learning project.

Comment: You might want to try increasing `min_lr`

Comment: I haven't got any improvement from 0.0001, 0.00001 and 0.000001